# How to set Query in FirebaseRecyclerOptions for showing child keys?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs8Zf.png)

This is my data structure...

I want to show all assignment names (Assignment No 1, Assignment No 2, etc.) in real-time in RecycleView.

```
 DatabaseReference dbr=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("22616 - Programming With Python").child("Assignments");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AssignmentModel1> options=
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AssignmentModel1>()
                    .setQuery(dbr,AssignmentModel1.class).build();
```

This is my code.

Comment: Check out [this post](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/database/readme/#using_firebaseui%20to%20populate%20a%20recyclerview). They also have a Github with a sample app you could take a look at.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Please help me @AlexMamo.

Comment: So you didn't right? Have tried something so far?

Comment: **I tried** to get keys using ValueEventListener. It works, but I want to get that data in real-time and update it in recycle view.@AlexMamo